# How to get the Id attribute of return json body response in groovy

Tags: json, groovy, azure-active-directory

After calling a MS Graph API using HttpBuilder which return user information, I would like to return the Id attribute of the Json response

The complete Json response is as below :

```
{
 @odata.context=https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users, 
 value=[{
         businessPhones=[], 
         displayName=Serge Cal GMAIL, 
         givenName=null, 
         jobTitle=null, 
         mail=user1.tom@gmail.com, 
         mobilePhone=null, 
         officeLocation=null, 
         preferredLanguage=null, 
         surname=null,
         userPrincipalName=user1.tom_gmail.com#EXT#@SCALDERARA.onmicrosoft.com, 
         id=253bca1d-6c03-441f-92e4-e206c7d180f7
       }]
}
```

For doing so I have a groovy method define as below :

```
public String getUserIdByEmailQuery(String AuthToken,String userEmail){

    String _userId

        def http = new HTTPBuilder(graph_base_user_url +"?")
        http.request(GET) {

            requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
            uri.query = [ $filter:"mail eq '$userEmail'".toString() ]

            headers.'Authorization' = "Bearer " + AuthToken    

            response.success = { resp, json ->
                **_userId=json["value"]["id"]**

            }

            // user ID not found : error 404
            response.'404' = { resp ->       
                _userId = 'Not Found'
            }

        }
        _userId
    }
```

With this update the reponse value is [xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-], which is correct excpet that it suround the value with []

Any idea ?

regards

Comment: It looks like your response is a JSON object containing a value, which itself is an object.  Does it work if you do `json.value.id` in your code?  I'm also concerned because it looks like `value` may be an array of maps (containing one map), so you may need to do something like `json.value[0].id`

Comment: The second concern mentioned by Daniel is right. The result data you get is an object and `value` is one item of it, `value` is also a array which contains multiple items. So you need to get the `value` from the response json first(use `json.value`) and then get the first item of the `value`(use `json.value[0]`) and use `json.value[0].id` to get the `id`.

Comment: @Hury Shen, See my update code.... if I use json["value"]["id"] it return the correct id value but surounded with bracket. how can I specifiy value[0] because it is effectively an array of user info but here in the sample response I have only 1 user. from the json object I cannot access it using json.value[0].id, this does not work

Answer (score 0):

The original problem was caused by the wrong expression to get the `id` and since you have got the id list `[xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx, xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx, ...]` by `json["value"]["id"]`, so you just need to use `json["value"]["id"][0]` to get the first id of the list.

And this expression `json["value"][0]["id"]` might also work.

**Update:**

You can use `groovy.json.JsonSlurper` to help you parse the json and get the `id` value.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(json)

String idValue = parsedJson.value[0].id
```

Comment: Hello Hury, this is what I try, json["value"][0]["id"] or json["value"]["id"][0] but I get a syntax error saying " Cannot find matching method as soon as I use the [0], any  idea?

Comment: Hi @SCW As it seems can't get the `id` directly from the json, you can import `groovy.json.JsonSlurper` package and use it to help you parse the json. Please refer to the "Update" in my answer.

Comment: Hi @Hury Shen, I have try the follwing :
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(json.toString()) and I get error " cannot assign java.lang.object to Map.

Casting it using as Map remove the error but then on the next line as  :
_userId = parsedJson.value[0].id I get error Method not found...

Comment: @SCW You can use `String jsonString = json.toString()` or `String jsonString = json.toPrettyString()` before `Map parsedJson = slurper.parseText(jsonString)`.